# sql with substring to a special character with sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have values with following format in a table in sqlite:

```
AAAAAAAAAA#BBBBBBBBBB

AAAA#BBBBBBBBBB

AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA#BBBBBBBBBBB
```

I would like to create a SQL where I get the following result:

```
AAAAAAAAAA

AAAA

AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

In other words. I would like to get the substring from 0->character `#`. 
How can I do this ?

Comment: [This is sql-server answer i aint no idea in sqlite syntax](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/14064)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please try:

```
SUBSTR(col,1,INSTR(col,'#') -1)
```

Can be found at:
http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html

Comment: Note that `instr()` was introduced only recently in 3.7.15 - many distros still have older versions of sqlite.

Comment: Thats exactly my problem. I guess I have an older version. instr() is not recognized. I have to check how to update an older db to a newer version.

Comment: Any solutions without INSTR()?

Comment: Testet and working even with widestrings / multi byte characters.

Answer (score 1):

Never used sqlite but something along the lines of `substr(yourfieldname, 1, instr(yourfieldname, '#') -1)` should do it.